# Binding JAX-RS bean validation error messages to the view

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy, bean-validation

We can easily validate a JAX-RS resource class field or method parameter using bean validation something like the following:

@Size(min = 18, max = 80, message = "Age must be between {min} and {max}.") String age;

What is the easiest way to bind the error message to a JSP page?

(Say, I am using Java EE 7 with Jersey or Resteasy)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**EDIT 1**

We introduced new annotation [@ErrorTemplate](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/mvc/ErrorTemplate.html) in Jersey 2.3 that covers this use-case. [Handling JAX-RS and Bean Validation Errors with MVC](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/01/28/handling-jax-rs-and-bean-validation-errors-with-mvc/) describes it deeper and shows how to use it.

---

With Jersey you can follow these steps:

1. add the following dependencies: `jersey-bean-validation` and `jersey-mvc-jsp`
2. create an [ExceptionMapper](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) for [ConstraintViolationException](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/1.1/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html)
3. register your providers

#### Dependencies

If you're using Maven you can simply add these dependencies to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

otherwise refer to the modules dependency pages to get a list of required libraries ([jersey-mvc-jsp](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.1/jersey/project/jersey-mvc-jsp/dependencies.html) and [jersey-bean-validation](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.1/jersey/project/jersey-bean-validation/dependencies.html)).

#### ExceptionMapper

Bean Validation runtime throws a ConstraintViolationException when something goes wrong during validation an entity (or JAX-RS resource). Jersey 2.x provides a standard ExceptionMapper to handle such exceptions (`ValidationException` to be precise) so if you want to handle them differently, you need to write an ExceptionMapper of your own:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.USER)
public class ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        return Response
                // Define your own status.
                .status(400)
                // Put an instance of Viewable in the response so that jersey-mvc-jsp can handle it.
                .entity(new Viewable("/error.jsp", exception))
                .build();
    }
}
```

With the ExceptionMapper above you'll be handling all thrown ConstraintViolationExceptions and the final response will have `HTTP 400` response status. Entity passed ([Viewable](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/mvc/Viewable.html)) to the response will be processed by MessageBodyWriter from `jersey-mvc` module and it will basically output a processed JSP page. The first parameter of the Viewable class is a path to a JSP page (you can use relative or absolute path), the second is the model the JSP will use for rendering (the model is accessible via `${it}` attribute in JSP). For more on this topic, refer to the section about [MVC](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html) in Jersey Users guide.

#### Registering Providers

The last step you need to make is to register your providers into your [Application](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) (I'll show you an example using [ResourceConfig](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) from Jersey which extends Application class):

```
new ResourceConfig()
    // Look for JAX-RS reosurces and providers.
    .package("my.package")
    // Register Jersey MVC JSP processor.
    .register(JspMvcFeature.class)
    // Register your custom ExceptionMapper.
    .register(ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper.class)
    // Register Bean Validation (this is optional as BV is automatically registered when jersey-bean-validation is on the classpath but it's good to know it's happening).
    .register(ValidationFeature.class);
```