# return any exception in json in rest api

Tags: java, json, api, rest, exception

Is there any simple methods to return exception in JSON using Rest api?
 I've already googled this question, but all solutions i see, was about throwing exceptions during some calculations. But what if income parameters are wrong? I mean what if there is sone string instead of int input parameter?

I created some DTO class for input data:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class RequestDTO implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@XmlElement(name = "request_id")
private String requestId;

@XmlElement(name = "site")
private List<String> sitesIds;

@XmlElement(name = "date_begin")
@JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializer.class)
private Date dateBegin;

@XmlElement(name = "date_end")
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateDeserializer.class)
private Date dateEnd;


@XmlElement(name = "volume")
private double volume;

// there is getters and setters
}
```

If i sent something like 'qwerty' instead of 'volume' field in my json request i'l see error message like Runtime. Is it possible to handle it in someway? I mean to return error in json with such structure?

```
public class ExceptionDTO {

private String shortExceptionMessage;
private String stackTrace;

public ExceptionDTO(String shotExceptionMessage, String stackTrace){
    this.shortExceptionMessage = shotExceptionMessage;
    this.stackTrace = stackTrace;
}

public String getShortExceptionMessage() {
    return shortExceptionMessage;
}

public String getStackTrace() {
    return stackTrace;
}
}
```

**UPD1:**

```
@Provider
@Singleton
public class ExceptionMapperProvider implements ExceptionMapper<Exception>{

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final Exception e) {

        StringBuilder trace = new StringBuilder();
        IntStream.range(0, e.getStackTrace().length)
            .forEach(i -> trace.append(e.getStackTrace()[i]).append('\n'));


        ExceptionDTO exceptionMessage = new ExceptionDTO(
                e.toString(),
                trace.toString()
         );

        return Response.status(500).entity(exceptionMessage).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: rest api? which specific jax-rs implementation are you using so i can provide a more specific answer?

Comment: @geneqew, i use jersey in my spring project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it's not really clear if you are interested on checking if field or value of the payload is correct, here are a few ways to work with both.

If you want to check if the `value` for a field is correct (ie volume field value should be greater than zero etc), check out [bean validation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html). [This](http://hibernate.org/validator/) makes use of annotations on the fields you want to verify.

```
// for example
@Min(value = 0, message = "invalid message")
private double range;
```

To use your ExceptionDTO as error response whenever one of those validation fails, you can do so by creating an `ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException>`. check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015630/binding-jax-rs-bean-validation-error-messages-to-the-view) for more details.

If you are checking for the invalid field (ie client sends ragne fields instead of range), have a look at the stack trace on what exception is being thrown. Then register an exception mapper with your `ExceptionDTO` as body.

For example, if `UnrecognizedPropertyException` is thrown then you can add:

```
@Provider
public class UnrecognizedPropertyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<UnrecognizedPropertyException> {

   @Override
   public Response toResponse(UnrecognizedPropertyException e) {
      ExceptionDTO myDTO = // build response
      return Response.status(BAD_REQUEST).entity(myDTO).build();
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But the main purpose for me is how to return any exception in json format from fields validation. I've created some exception mapper (you can see it in topic update), but what i should do with it? When it should be executed?

Comment: By the way... is it possible to round all rest api in some try-catch block to catch any exception?

Comment: basically the flow is client calls your resource endpoint passing your RequestDTO as payload, if there is a violation and exception is thrown which will be mapped by your exception mapper. Your exception mapper will produce the response (in your case ExceptionDTO). do not forget to include the dependency `jersey-bean-validation` and enable bean validation. Read [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html) on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I did a bit of research and determined that the best way to encode a Java exception in JSON is to use a convention developed by Oasis that looks like this:

```
{
   "error": {
      "code": "400",
      "message": "main error message here",
      "target": "approx what the error came from",
      "details": [
         {
            "code": "23-098a",
            "message": "Disk drive has frozen up again.  It needs to be replaced",
            "target": "not sure what the target is"
         }
      ],
      "innererror": {
         "trace": [ ... ],
         "context": [ ... ]
      }
   }
}
```

`details` is a list that should have an entry for each nested cause exception in the chain.

`innererror.trace` should include the stack trace if you wish, as a list of string values.

The response status code should be 400 unless you have a good reason for making it something else, and the code in the structure should match whatever you sent.

Write one method to convert a Java exception to this format, and you are done.  Use it consistently and your JS code will be able to handle and display the exception values.

More of the details of the other approaches evaluated and dismissed are covered in this blog post on *JSON REST API – Exception Handling*
[https://agiletribe.purplehillsbooks.com/2015/09/16/json-rest-api-exception-handling/](https://agiletribe.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/json-rest-api-exception-handling/)

Here is the java method to convert an exception to this format:

```
public static JSONObject convertToJSON(Exception e, String context) throws Exception {
    JSONObject responseBody = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject errorTag = new JSONObject();
    responseBody.put("error", errorTag);

    errorTag.put("code", 400);
    errorTag.put("target", context);

    JSONArray detailList = new JSONArray();
    errorTag.put("details", detailList);

    String lastMessage = "";
    Throwable runner = e;
    while (runner!=null) {
        String className =  runner.getClass().getName();
        String msg =  runner.toString();

        runner = runner.getCause();

        JSONObject detailObj = new JSONObject();
        detailObj.put("message",msg);
        int dotPos = className.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (dotPos>0) {
            className = className.substring(dotPos+1);
        }
        detailObj.put("code",className);
        System.out.println("          ERR: "+msg);
        detailList.put(detailObj);
    }

    JSONObject innerError = new JSONObject();
    errorTag.put("innerError", innerError);

    JSONArray stackList = new JSONArray();
    runner = e;
    while (runner != null) {
        for (StackTraceElement ste : runner.getStackTrace()) {
            String line = ste.getFileName() + ":" + ste.getMethodName() + ":" + ste.getLineNumber();
            stackList.put(line);
        }
        stackList.put("----------------");
        runner = runner.getCause();
    }
    errorTag.put("stack", stackList);
    return responseBody;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate input parameters in the request, you should return status code 400 (Bad Request) along with the error details. You can simply send json 
`{ "error": { "message": "string received for parameter x, where as int expected" }` with the response status code 400.

`

Comment: I know ho to return Resonse with my ExceptionDTO during some calculations. But the question was about how to catch the exception during deserialising parameters?