# How to check for required form parameter using JAX-RS?

Tags: jax-rs, form-parameter

I have a POST method call which accepts few form parameters. I want JAX-RS to handle the situation where a particular form parameter is not present.

Example :

`@POST 
@Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public Response makeCall(@FormParam("input") final String input) {
}`

Now if I don't pass any value for "input", the control comes into this method and considers the value of input as null.

But I don't want the control to come into this method when the value of input is null.

Any ideas on how can we achieve that ?

Can JAX-RS throw error 400 (Bad Request) when a required form parameter is not present ?

Comment: I think you answer can be found in this other thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968261/required-queryparam-in-jax-rs-and-what-to-do-in-their-absence

Answer (score 1):

With JAX-RS 2.0 implementations, you can use the `@NotNull` annotation provided by the Bean Validation spec to ensure that the `@FormParam("input")` value is not null.

See https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html

HTH.

Comment: Hi @XavierCoulon, I tried with bean validation @NotNull, but still the control goes into the method and it considers the value of the missing element as `null`. When reading the documents, i see that it should fail with either 500 or 400 error. But its not. Am i doing something wrong? I have used below dependency 
`<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: I guess it depends on the JAX-RS implementation you use. The Bean Validation API only is probably not enough, you certainly need to include an optional dependency that will provide *support* for Bean Validation in the JAX-RS implementation. For example, see the dependencies Jersey requires (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e11712) and the ones that RESTEasy requires (https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html/Validation.html#d4e2461). HTH.

Comment: NotNull is valid when the form param comes in as an empty String. Consider extending NotNull into NotBlank.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem. The following fix might work (at least it works for me):

```
@POST 
@Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public Response makeCall(@Valid @FormParam("input") final String input) {
}
```

Note this `@Valid` annotation.

Comment: In my trying this, it has the same problem as @Nonnull, my API produces a 500 instead of a 400.

Answer (score 0):

When `@NotNull` doesn't work, you can check it by yourself.

```java
if (input == null) {
    throw new javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I could not find @NotNull in JAX-RS specification. Is that annotation is implementation-specific?

Comment: @HieuHT That's from the Bean Validation

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks @Jin Kwon