# Jersey Client / JAX-RS and optional (not default) @QueryParam (client side)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a RESTful API who's document says that a certain query parameter is optional, and does not supply a default argument.  So, I can either supply the value or not send it in the GET request as a parameter.

Example:

- `queryA` is required
- `queryB` is **optional** (can send `GET` without it)

This should work:

```
http://www.example.com/service/endpoint?queryA=foo&queryB=bar
```

This should also work:

```
http://www.example.com/service/endpoint?queryA=foo
```

How do I make an client interface for [Jersey-Proxy](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.9/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/proxy/package-summary.html) that can do this?? **I do not have the server-side code** to interface with so I am using `org.glassfish.jersey.client.proxy.WebResourceFactory` via Jersey-Proxy to generate the client to interact with the server API.

Sample interface:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/service")
@Produces("application/json")
public interface ServiceInterface {

    @Path("/endpoint")
    @GET
    public Response getEndpoint(
            @QueryParam("queryA") String first,
            @QueryParam("queryB") String second);

}
```

I know I can make another method:

```
    @Path("/endpoint")
    @GET
    public Response getEndpoint(
            @QueryParam("queryA") String first);
```

But what happens when you have multiple optional fields?? I don't want to make every possible mutation of them!

Comment: This may answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968261/required-queryparam-in-jax-rs-and-what-to-do-in-their-absence

Comment: That is for server-side, not client-side.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## The interface was right all along

I can't believe it was this easy:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/service")
@Produces("application/json")
public interface ServiceInterface {

    @Path("/endpoint")
    @GET
    public Response getEndpoint(
            @QueryParam("queryA") String first,
            @QueryParam("queryB") String second);

}
```

Notice anything different than the questions interface?? Nope.  That's because that is the answer!

---

## Don't use @DefaultValue for optional parameters

If you want to default a parameter to a specific value, you use the `@DefaultValue` annotation in the parameter:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/service")
@Produces("application/json")
public interface ServiceInterface {

    @Path("/endpoint")
    @GET
    public Response getEndpoint(
            @QueryParam("queryA") String first,
            @QueryParam("queryB") @DefaultValue("default") String second);

}
```

---

## Pass `null` to the `@QueryParam` you don't want

**If you want to make the `@QueryParam` optional, you do not apply the `@DefaultValue` annotation.**  To pass a value with the query parameter, just pass in the value normally.  If you would like the query parameter to not show up at all, just pass `null`!

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/service")
@Produces("application/json")
public interface ServiceInterface {

    @Path("/endpoint")
    @GET
    public Response getEndpoint(
            @QueryParam("queryA") String first,
            // Pass null to this parameter to not put it in the GET request
            @QueryParam("queryB") String second);

}
```

So calling `ServiceInterface.getEndpoint("firstQueryParam", "secondQueryParam");` calls:

```
http://targethost.com/service/endpoint?queryA=firstQueryParam&queryB=secondQueryParam
```

and calling `ServiceInterface.getEndpoint("firstQueryParam", null);` calls:

```
http://targethost.com/service/endpoint?queryA=firstQueryParam
```

And walla! No second query parameter! :)

### Note on primitive values

If your API takes primitive values (like `int`, `float`, `boolean`, etc), then use the object wrapper class ([Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)) for that primitive (like `Integer`, `Float`, `Boolean`, etc). Then, you can pass `null` to the method:

```
public Response getEndpoint(@QueryParam("queryA") Boolean first);
```

Comment: what about numbers in stead of strings? There is no way of using null, so you have to check value.

Comment: I believe to do that you need to use the auto-boxes types: `Boolean`, `Integer`, etc....

Comment: Jersey is very annoying if you need to maintain multiple client and they can't all upgrade to your new API, basically it forces you to introduce a breaking change in your interface for an optional query param

Answer (score 3):

You can inject a `UriInfo` instance (or something else like `HttpServletRequest`) into your method, and get whatever data you want off of it.

For example

```
@Path("/endpoint")
@GET
public Response getEndpoint(@Context UriInfo info, @QueryParam("queryA") String queryA) {
  String queryB = info.getQueryParameters().getFirst("queryB");
  if (null != queryB) {
    // do something with it
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does this work with `WebResourceFactory` with Jersey off the top of your head?  I'll look into seeing if I can do this...

Comment: You mention Jersey client, but as far as I can tell your example is the server-side definition of a JAX-RS endpoint...

Comment: The definition is for client-side, as I do not have the server-side code.

Comment: Ok I understand, I'm not sure if you can use the `@Context` style injection then... but it may work.