# REST without parameter value?

Tags: java, rest, url, java-8, jnlp

I have a jnlp application which accepts rest parameters.

Examples:

1. localhost:8080/myApp/rest//jnlp/Client
2. localhost:8080/myApp/rest//jnlp/Client?id
3. localhost:8080/myApp/rest//jnlp/Client?id=

Example 1 and 2 work fine. However, how can I react on the last case? I can run it without parameter, with id but not with id=. That gets me a WebApplicationException. What could I do to allow the third case?

Comment: Can you please add the resource class's code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways are to handle the same.
Please refer the probable solutions in the following link:
[Jersey Client / JAX-RS and optional (not default) @QueryParam (client side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147032/jersey-client-jax-rs-and-optional-not-default-queryparam-client-side)