# How to check REST invalid query parameter name with RESTEasy?

Tags: java, resteasy

How to fail on invalid query parameter name with RESTEasy?

Consider a valid REST request like this one: `/list?sort-by=date`

Then, user makes this request: `/list?sort_by=date`

See that user replaced **hyphen** with **underscore**. It works, but it will ignore parameter and use default sorting (param not mandatory).

With Jackson, if a JSON with invalid member is sent it throws an Exception. I would like a similar behavior to query params (header params would be awesome too). Tested with `@BeanParam`, but apparently it doesn't use Jackson in this case.

RESTEasy version 3.15.1.

Comment: What version of RESTEasy are you using?

Comment: Sorry @james-r-perkins, edited question. RESTEasy 3.15.1

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that in your code. Query params are not in json in standard, you can do that with a class with string constructor.
In fact "sort_by" is not bind to a method parameter, so it's ignored.
If you want that "sort-by" to be mandatory you have to do that in your code :

[Required @QueryParam in JAX-RS (and what to do in their absence)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968261/required-queryparam-in-jax-rs-and-what-to-do-in-their-absence)

> Currently since RESTEasy is built on top of a Servlet, it does not distinguish between URI query strings or url form encoded parameters. Like PathParam, your parameter type can be an String, primitive, or class that has a String constructor or static valueOf() method.

https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.15.1.Final/userguide/html_single/#_QueryParam

Comment: "Query params are not in json in standard, you can do that with a class with string constructor": can you elaborate more on this? Also, 'required' isn't an option, it's not a mandatory param, as - poorly ;) - explained, it has a default value/behavior.